# JavaFX application with remote DB

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I'm developing a desktop application in JavaFX with login system and some data that must be saved in a remote database. The question is: What it's the best way to stablish a database connection with each user with the server? Should I use a RESTful API or connect to database using the remote host just like if it was a local DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of data are you looking to manipulate? Depending on exactly how much control you may need over the information (and how secure it must be?) if you don't need an absolutely synchronized view of the information (re: the server side app having a persistent connection to the client which is informed on change events and such) it may be best to just build up a RESTful API to do all of your grunt work between the two.

If you're coming to the RESTful api and also have to design it I suggest giving this a good read. [Best Practices for a Pragmatic RESTful API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is just simple CRUDs with an user system. It is a bad practice to use a remote MySQL database? How softwares like this are usually made?

Comment: The usual practice is that you create an API (REST-styled would be simplest for your needs) and build that to do operations upon the database. Most applications don't expose the raw mysql operations outright as far as I know.